# How to write a function that conducts paired t-tests on all group/variable combinations in a data frame

Tags: r, function, loops, comparison

I have a data frame similar to `data` created below:

```r
ID <- data.frame(ID=rep(c(12,122,242,329,595,130,145,245,654,878),each=5))
Var <- data.frame(Variable=c("Copper","Iron","Lead","Zinc","CaCO"))
n <- 10
Variable <- do.call("rbind",replicate(n,Var,simplify=F))
Location <- rep(c("Alpha","Beta","Gamma"), times=c(20,20,10))
Location <- data.frame(Location)
set.seed(1)
FirstPt<- data.frame(FirstPt=sample(1:100,50,replace=T))
LastPt <- data.frame(LastPt=sample(1:100,50,replace=T))
First3<- data.frame(First3=sample(1:100,50,replace=T))
First5<- data.frame(First5=sample(1:100,50,replace=T))
First7<- data.frame(First7=sample(1:100,50,replace=T))
First10<- data.frame(First10=sample(1:100,50,replace=T))
Last3<- data.frame(Last3=sample(1:100,50,replace=T))
Last5<- data.frame(Last5=sample(1:100,50,replace=T))
Last7<- data.frame(Last7=sample(1:100,50,replace=T))
Last10<- data.frame(Last10=sample(1:100,50,replace=T))
data <- cbind(ID,Location,Variable,FirstPt,LastPt,First3,First5,First7,
              First10,Last3,Last5,Last7,Last10)
```

This may be a two part question, but I want to write a function that groups all `Variables` that are the same (for instance, all the observations that are `Copper`) and conducts a paired t test between all possible combinations of the numeric columns (`FirstPt`:`Last10`). I want it to return the p values in a data frame like this:

```r
Test                        P-Value
FirstPt.vs.LastPt             …
FirstPt.vs.First3             … 
ect...                        …
```

This will likely be a second function, but I also want to do this after the observations are grouped by `Location` so that the output data frame will look like this:

```r
Test                                   P-Value
FirstPt.vs.LastPt.InAlpha
FirstPt.vs.LastPt.InBeta        
ect...
```

Comment: Take a look at `combn` as a way to get a list with all of the possible combinations, and then use `lapply` to iterate your operations (e.g., paired t-test) over the elements of that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do both of these with one function:

```
library(tidyverse)

t.test.by.group.combos <- function(.data, groups){
  by <-  gsub(x = rlang::quo_get_expr(enquo(groups)), pattern = "\\((.*)?\\)", replacement = "\\1")[-1]
  .data %>%
    group_by(!!!groups) %>%
    select_if(is.integer) %>%
    group_split() %>%
    map(.,
      ~pivot_longer(., cols = (FirstPt:Last10), names_to = "name", values_to = "val") %>%
        nest(data = val) %>%
        full_join(.,.,by = by) %>%
        filter(name.x != name.y) %>%
        mutate(test = paste(name.x, "vs",name.y, !!!groups, sep = "."),
               p.value = map2_dbl(data.x,data.y, ~t.test(unlist(.x), unlist(.y))$p.value)) %>%
        select(test,p.value)%>%
      filter(!duplicated(p.value))
    ) %>%
    bind_rows() 
}


t.test.by.group.combos(data, vars(Variable))
#> # A tibble: 225 x 2
#>    test                    p.value
#>    <chr>                     <dbl>
#>  1 FirstPt.vs.LastPt.CaCO    0.511
#>  2 FirstPt.vs.First3.CaCO    0.184
#>  3 FirstPt.vs.First5.CaCO    0.494
#>  4 FirstPt.vs.First7.CaCO    0.354
#>  5 FirstPt.vs.First10.CaCO   0.893
#>  6 FirstPt.vs.Last3.CaCO     0.496
#>  7 FirstPt.vs.Last5.CaCO     0.909
#>  8 FirstPt.vs.Last7.CaCO     0.439
#>  9 FirstPt.vs.Last10.CaCO    0.146
#> 10 LastPt.vs.First3.CaCO     0.578
#> # … with 215 more rows

t.test.by.group.combos(data, vars(Variable, Location))
#> # A tibble: 674 x 2
#>    test                          p.value
#>    <chr>                           <dbl>
#>  1 FirstPt.vs.LastPt.CaCO.Alpha    0.850
#>  2 FirstPt.vs.First3.CaCO.Alpha    0.822
#>  3 FirstPt.vs.First5.CaCO.Alpha    0.895
#>  4 FirstPt.vs.First7.CaCO.Alpha    0.810
#>  5 FirstPt.vs.First10.CaCO.Alpha   0.645
#>  6 FirstPt.vs.Last3.CaCO.Alpha     0.870
#>  7 FirstPt.vs.Last5.CaCO.Alpha     0.465
#>  8 FirstPt.vs.Last7.CaCO.Alpha     0.115
#>  9 FirstPt.vs.Last10.CaCO.Alpha    0.474
#> 10 LastPt.vs.First3.CaCO.Alpha     0.991
#> # … with 664 more rows
```

This is kind of a lengthy function, but in general we group by the `groups` argument, then we select the groups and any integer columns, then we split the dataframe by the groups. After, we map all the combinations of variables and perform t.tests for each combo. Lastly, we rejoin all the groups into one dataframe.

Comment: some parts of this function are quite out of my knowledge base. but I am trying to figure it out. It does exactly what I want for the example data I provided. When I try to implement it on another dataset though, I cannot get it to work. I get this error code: `Error in x:y : NA/NaN argument`. the only difference between the data sets is the names of the first 3 columns, is there anything I would need to change in the function in this case?

Comment: @Ryan what does `class(data$FirstPt)` return?

Comment: Also, which parts of the function do you find confusing? I'd be happy to explain.

Comment: that returns "numeric". The name of the data frame is `PtData` instead of `data`,  `Location` is changed to `Region`, `ID` is changed `IdNum`, and `Variable` is changed to `Element`. From left to right they are `IdNum` `Element` `River`. also the levels of each have different names (copper is Cu, ect..) but I don't think that matters.

Comment: That would be great! I am unfamiliar with `gsub()` in general, I just need to read through the help file. Here are the things I dont yet understand: I don't know exactly what the `.`s and `!`s refer to or do in your code (`.data`, `full_join(.,)`,`!!!groups` ,ect...). Also the use of the dot and tilde in: `map(., ~pivot_longer(.,)`,  and what `by=by` does in `full_join()`

Comment: Okay, I think the only thing you need to change is `select_if(is.integer)` to `select_at(vars(FirstPt:Last10))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206539/discussion-between-ands-and-ryan).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. The key was to use group_by and do from tidyverse.

```
df <- NULL
for(i in (4:(ncol(data)-1))){
  for(j in ((i+1):ncol(data))){
    df <- rbind(df,data %>% 
                  group_by(Location) %>% 
                  do(data.frame(pval = t.test(.[[i]],.[[j]], data = .)$p.value)) %>% 
                  ungroup() %>% 
                  mutate(Test = paste0(colnames(data)[i],'.vs.',colnames(data)[j]))
                )
  }
}
df$Test <- paste0(df$Test,'.In',df$Location)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you can acheive what you want using the below code :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = FirstPt:Last10) %>%
  group_by(Variable) %>%
  summarise(p_value = list(combn(name, 2, function(x) 
                       t.test(value[name == x[1]], value[name == x[2]])$p.value)), 
            test = list(combn(name, 2, paste, collapse = "_"))) %>%
  unnest(cols = c(test, p_value))


#  Variable p_value test           
#   <fct>      <dbl> <chr>          
# 1 CaCO       0.915 FirstPt_LastPt 
# 2 CaCO       0.529 FirstPt_First3 
# 3 CaCO       0.337 FirstPt_First5 
# 4 CaCO       0.350 FirstPt_First7 
# 5 CaCO       0.395 FirstPt_First10
# 6 CaCO       0.765 FirstPt_Last3  
# 7 CaCO       0.204 FirstPt_Last5  
# 8 CaCO       0.873 FirstPt_Last7  
# 9 CaCO       0.479 FirstPt_Last10 
#10 CaCO       1     FirstPt_FirstPt
# … with 24,740 more rows
```

To do it grouped by `Location` you can add that into `group_by` command and keep rest of the code as it is.